# Probability puzzle on expected value

Tags: math, probability

A friend of yours proposes a game: if you correctly guess the amount of money in his wallet, the cash is yours; otherwise, you get nothing. You're allowed a single guess.

You believe there's a 50 percent chance your friend has $0 in his wallet, a 25 percent chance of $1, 24 percent of $100 and — excitingly — a one percent chance he has $1,000.

What dollar amount should you guess in order to maximize your expected winnings?

Comment: This should be in "puzzling", right?

Comment: @EduardoWada sure sir.. will post next ones there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can argue like this: suppose that you take a guess N times with N approaching infinity, and you must always guess the same amount. What would you earn if your constant guess was $1? [There is no point betting $0.] Well, 25% of the time you would win, so your earnings would be 0.25*N*($1) = $(0.25*N).

Likewise, if your guess was $100 you would win 24% of the time, so your earnings would be 0.24*N*($100) = $(24*N), and if your guess was $1000 you would win 1% of the time, yielding 0.01*N*($1000) = $(10*N).

So, the guess which maximizes the earnings (in the sense described) is $100.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Revisiting the answer, I see it is not quite correct; the thought experiment should instead be "suppose the game is repeated N times with N approaching infinity, and you must always guess the same amount". Your friend changes each time the wallet's content, according to the probabilities stated: 50% $0, 25% $1, 24% $100, 1% $1000.
The rest of the explanation remains as is.